# Nested remote-desktop-plus connections

Tags: remote-access

I sometimes need to connect to a machine using remote-desktop plus, and from there set up a new remote-desktop connection to yet another machine. Is there a way to automate this using commandline options or an .rdp file?

I can "automate" everything including logging in through a gateway like this:

```
rdp.exe  /v:some-host /u:DOMAIN\johndoe /p:NSAbackD00R /o:"gatewayhostname:s:remote-host.fqdn.tld, gatewayusagemethod:i:1, gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:1, promptcredentialonce:i:1"
```

It would be nice if it was possible to add some more options so that the second connection was setup automatically.

Comment: added some details :)

Comment: I'm hoping that isn't a real password :)

Comment: Yes it is a real password, built into every system on the planet :)

Comment: I'm not sure how you achieve what you want, but, what if a script was run from the destination PC/Server when it detects a certain user logging in?

Comment: yeah thats probably possible, I was just hoping that someone already had made a simple solution :)

Answer (score 0):

That would be a significant security issue I would think if you could script access to several levels of nested server.

No, you cannot do this. What you *could* do if you have the rights is to add a scheduled task that runs at login on the remote servers that kicks off a connection to the next step.

Comment: Why would that be a security issue?

Comment: You are effectively hoping from client A to server B then server C from a command on A, I'd need to think it through but that doesn't sound quite right to me I suspect you could easily end up with unexpected consequences. Each step should be in control of the connection to the next & I think your suggestion might undermine that. Not sure. Anyway, it can't be done.

Comment: And? I gain access due to having credentials (password etc.) and every connection to C happens through B from A either way. Why would there suddenly be security issues or unexpected results just because I no longer would have to click icons?